# What other sites do you go to for your coding questions?

Tags: resources, reference

This site is pretty good but I'm wondering what other resources are out there.  I guess it's probably pretty language dependent but in general I have not found any other sites with a good wealth of general programming knowledge where I can just post a question and someone will actually answer it.  Especially when you're posting some sort of question or problem that spans multiple technologies.  Also I cannot tell you how many times someone has asked the same (or a very similar) question as mine and I find a Google link to that damn "Experts Exchange" site where they hide the answers.

Comment: If you listen to the SO podcasts you'll see that the main reason for creating SO was because of the Experts Exchange asshattery.

Comment: keep scrolling to the bottom and you can read the answers on experts exchange

Comment: Not any more, I think (at least not in Chrome). Not even the google cache trick seems to work these days.

Comment: Very Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353269/relation-with-experts-exchange

Comment: Also, Argumentative; if it stays open, please edit/wiki.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, Google.  95% of what I am looking for has usually been asked before.  I end up landing on various blogs.  I never realized how many development blogs are really out there.  I used to prefer Usenet for questions and answers, but that is just showing my age.

Answer (score 7):

Generally codeproject, or just a straightforward google search.

Comment: For me (as a .NET developer) it's google first then codeproject.

Comment: Yeah... same here actually. Typically google will lead me to codeproject :) (or some random blog)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.google.com and this one.  StackOverflow has proven to be a great tool in my arsenal.  Having started a new job (working mosly on the DB side of things) I've come to rely on this website, but google is the other one I frequently pull up.

Answer (score 2):

For dotNet questions you can't beat http://www.searchdotnet.com/default.aspx
a custom google search maintained by Dan Appleman.

Answer (score 1):

SQLServerCentral is fantastic for DB stuff

Answer (score 1):

When I first started developing FF Extensions, I made heavy use (although mainly as a lurker) of [Mozillazine forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/). Great people, great knowledge.

In regards of Experts Exchange, I hate to state the obvious, but they do have their answers all the way at the bottom of the page, as long as you come from Google. That's what you meant by "hide the answers", right? I believe Chrome didn't work like that but it seems like they recognize Chrome's user agent too now.

Answer (score 1):

I tend not to ask a lot of questions on sites, but I do answer them on Code Project. That's a really good site, and some of my other CP friends come here to answer questions - in fact, they were the ones who got me into SO in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Code Search](http://google.com/codesearch) is often useful.

Answer (score 1):

I almost always start with Google.  Sometimes I go directly to Code Project.  They tend to feature lengthy tutorials with sample code.  When I was new to ASP and ASP.NET I used https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/ but I don't need that anymore.  But these have worked for me only because the question I wanted to ask had already been asked (by someone else) and (luckily) answered as well.

I haven't had much luck with the news groups, mostly cause the volume of posting is so high that unless your question is answered in the first few hours, it rapidly gets pushed down where no one will ever see it again.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com) from time to time. Don't let the site fool you, personal accounts are free.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, Stack Overflow. Barring that, wherever Google takes me.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently run into experts-exchange while doing web searches and usually startle coworkers with foul language when it happens. However, here is a trick I use:

Install web developer (plugin) for Firefox. When you have the bad luck to need an answer from experts-exchange, disable CSS completely. They're using CSS to hide the answers and disabling it will give you some plaintext. You can search for "accepted solution" to get to it, if there is one for the question.

As an aside, I am extremely happy to support SO because of the completely different approach to making Q&A and knowledge accessible and free.

Answer (score 0):

Google, Google Code Search and "Google Groups", Clusty to narrow it down when there are too many results and sometimes Yahoo can find other or newer results.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tek-tips.com/index.cfm

http://lessthandot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am a .Net Developer here is a list of some of the sites that I regularly use to get coding information.

**Forums**

http://stackoverflow.com

http://forums.asp.net/

http://forums.msdn.microsoft.com/

**Code Examples and Information**

http://www.codeproject.com

http://www.searchdotnet.com

http://www.w3schools.com/

http://www.codeplex.com/

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/

http://channel9.msdn.com/

http://www.dnrtv.com/

http://www.asp.net/ajax/

**Magazines:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/default.aspx

http://www.code-magazine.com/

**Blogs:**

http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

I find that it's helpful to use the mailing lists of the tools that you're using (if your question is for a specific tool). Mailing lists tend to have a community directly involved with the tool and also usually get responses from the tool developers themselves, which is very useful.

Mailing lists are usually indexed on the web, too, so you don't necessarily have to subscribe. [Nabble](http://www.nabble.com/) is one such indexing site.